KJV v.s. NLT translations
As I understand, the King James Version of the Bible is the closest translation to the original spoken words that the apostles actually wrote themselves. Knowing this, why would other authors of different translations of the Bible confuse the reader if both texts? In the KJV version, it says "...the ark of God". whereas the NLT version says"...the ephod"!?!?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A specific chapter and verse would be needed to answer this question

@user66261 -  you are referring to 1 Samuel 14:18 ... please put this in your question or you are liable to have your question closed.

I upvoted the question because it is interesting, even though it does need a reference.

The OP asks about the translation of 1 Samuel 14:18. Translators are roughly equally divided as to whether it is the ark or the ephod here. This basically boils down to the Hebrew (Masoretic) vs. the Greek (Septuagint) text, but there are good reasons to opt for "ephod" in any case. First, is the fact that ark resided somewhere else.
1 Samuel 7:2

From the day the ark came to rest in Kiriath-jearim, a long time,
twenty years, elapsed, and the whole house of Israel turned to the
Lord.

Here are  the two translations mentioned in the OP plus a translation of the Septuagint.
1 Samuel 14:18

KJV - And Saul said unto Ahiah, Bring hither the ark of God. For the ark of God was at that time with the children of Israel.
NLT - Then Saul shouted to Ahijah, “Bring the ephod here!” For at that
time Ahijah was wearing the ephod in front of the Israelites.
Brenton's Septuagint - And Saul said to Achia, Bring the ephod ; for
he wore the ephod in that day before Israel.

The Hebrew noun in question is אֲר֧וֹן which is normally translated as "ark."  However, besides the fact that the ark resided elsewhere, another problem is that the action described (divination) is not something that was done with the ark but was indeed done with the ephod. Moreover, at the beginning of the chapter, Ahijah is wearing the "ephod" - even in the KJV - and the ark is not described as being at the scene.

2 Saul was sitting under the pomegranate tree in Migron... with him
were about six hundred men. 3 Ahijah... the priest of the Lord at
Shiloh, was wearing the ephod. (KJV)

Later in the chapter (36-41) Saul consults God through Urim and Thummin, which are associated with the ephod but not with the ark.
Conclusion:  It makes no sense that Saul would call to Ahijah to bring the "ark" when Ahijah was wearing the "ephod" - especially because what Saul apparently wanted to consult Urim and Thummin to inquire of God. Also, the ark is elsewhere described as residing Kiriath-jearim. Translators have thus opted for the Septuagint over the Masoretic (Hebrew) version here.
